# getting "Internal Server Error " on invalid pages after editing htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I added this to my htaccess on my local mamp server:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L,QSA]
```

This makes URLs work without the .php extension and it works fine. However if I go on a page that does not exist I get the "Internal Server Error" not the 404 page not found one...

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because the rule match, conds 1 and 2 are all true.  You need to stop the loop if the URL already contains .php so

```
RewriteRule   ^(.*)(?<!\.php)$      $1.php [L,QSA]
```

This means match .* so long as the end anchor isn't preceded by `.php`